# What does "I feel for that" mean?

Tags: idioms

"I feel for that" I keep hearing this phrase all around.  I wonder what it means.

Can anyone elaborate?

Comment: By the way, I think you mean "elaborate", not "collaborate"...

Answer (score 4):

I think what you are hearing is the slightly longer phrase: "I feel for that *NOUN*", which is a variant of *I feel for NP*:

> I feel for [him].
>   I feel for [John].
>   I feel for [the parents].
>   I feel for [anybody who has to eat her cooking].
>   I feel for [that guy who had his house swallowed by a sinkhole].
>   I feel for [that poor SOB in Minnesota].

*Feel for* expresses your sympathy for the object of *for*: you feel sympathy or grief or dismay *for* that person or those people.